# how to load an external js file after a page loads and use a function from it

Tags: javascript, html

I need to load an external js file into a html file AFTER the page loads. This is because in this external js file a variable only updates itself after the html file loads.
that being said i also need to use the function showScreen afterwards. showScreen is a boolean in the external js file.

I only want it to switch screens when showscreen is true and that can only load after the html file loads. So right now if i did window.onload = showScreen in the html, it is always undefined

external.js  ( this is part of the external file and the function Im trying to use)

```
function showScreen(showTraditionalScreen) {
   console.log("showTraditionalScreen "+ showTraditionalScreen);
   return showTraditionalScreen;
}
```

UPDATE:

index.html (this is the bottom half of the file where i want to make the changes)

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/additions.js"></script>
        <script src="../server/webcam.js" defer></script>
        <script>
           if(window.onload =showScreen)
              window.location.href = "traditional.html";
           }
       </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

it currently doesnt do anything, but the point is, when showScreen is true the page will change to traditional.html. Currently it doesnt do that

this file is also asynchronous, so the console.log continues to print true or false

I know ajax is a good option and i have been experimenting but im still a little lost.

how do i use the external.js function in an html file after the page loads?
Why isnt my file currently allowing me to use showscreen?

Comment: have you tried `window.onload` or `$(document).ready` if using jquery?

Comment: i cant use those because the page needs to load first

Comment: That's the point of using those. They tell the javascript inside them to wait to execute until after the page loads.

Comment: i should been more clear, that works HOWEVER, i only want it to switch screens when showscreen is true and that can only load after the html file loads. so it doesnt work for my purposes because window.onload = showScreen is always undefined

Comment: I _think_ I see what you're saying. The way you've tried `window.onload = showScreen`, the method definition has already run, and I think it's returning undefined because it's already checked for the element in question, but it's not there until the page loads. I would suggest wrapping the function definition itself in `window.onload` so that you don't look for the element until you know it's on the screen.

Comment: right but my bigger issue is the output of showScreen is located in a different file so im not sure how to access it in the html file @katniss.everbean

Comment: Can you provide more code? Enough to demonstrate the pattern you're trying to use (ie relevant code in all of the relevant external js files and the relevant code in your HTML file).

Comment: I added more relevant code! thank you so so much for still being invested @katniss.everbean

Answer (score 2):

you can use `defer`

```
<script src="path" defer></script>
```

This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded. The defer attribute is only for external scripts (should only be used if the src attribute is present).

Comment: This would be a more complete answer if you described what defer does and how they might use it to solve their problem.

Comment: what boolean attribute?

Comment: `defer` is the boolean attribute. If you add it to the script tag, it will defer loading of that script until after the document is parsed, but if you don't add it, the script is loaded as soon as the browser gets to it.

Comment: i dont think this works, i used defer and also printed out an alert and it popped up even before the page was loaded

Answer (score 0):

#### wrap the function call in a window.onload

It looks like `if(window.onload = showScreen)` might be checking if the assignment to the onload variable happens, as opposed to checking that the return of `showScreen` is true. Is that your intention? I think this will return true before the page finishes loading (if it succeeds), so it's not useful as a way to check that the page has loaded if that's what you wanted.

Your `showScreen` function takes a parameter. When you assign a function like this to `onload` the way you've done, you're passing in a single default 'event' parameter. If that's what you wanted, maybe that's what you mean by "This is because in this external js file a variable only updates itself after the html file loads."?

I also think you're missing an opening bracket at the end of the first line of the `if` statement, so that could be causing problems.

Here's another stab at providing what you want. In the following code, I'm waiting for the page to load, and once it has I'm checking to see if the `showScreen` function returns true. Assuming you needed the page load event as a parameter, I've passed that through to your `showScreen` function. Otherwise I'm not sure where the `showTraditionalScreen` param is coming from.

```
<script>
  window.onload( function(event){
    if(showScreen(event)) {
      window.location.href = "traditional.html";
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: i set the showTraditionalScreen output in the external file so this wont work because showScreen is always undefined